# Numpy cumsum with lower limit (vectorized)

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I have an array and I would like to get the cumulative sum imposing a lower bound (lb=0) because in my array I have negative elements. Is it possible to vectorize it? I tried with a loop and `numba.njit` but the execution is slower than pure Python. Below an example of what I would like to get.

Example array:

```
a = numpy.array([1,1,-1,-1,-1,1,1])
```

What I get with `numpy.cumsum`:

```
[ 1  2  1  0 -1  0  1]
```

What I want:

```
[ 1  2  1  0  0  1  2]
```

The function with loop:

```
@numba.njit
def cumsum(array, lb=0):
    result = numpy.zeros(array.size)
    result[0] = array[0]
    for k in range(1, array.size):
        result[k] = max(lb, result[k-1]+array[k])
    return result
```

Comment: When I execute the above, Numba is way faster than pure Python. Note that the first call to `cumsum()` (when decorated with `@numba.njit`) also does the compilation, so to be fair you should not time this first call. The second (and third and ...) call to `cumsum()` will be fast.

Comment: @jmd_dk thanks! If you answer the question in the dedicated section, I will accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I execute the above, Numba is way faster than pure Python. Note that the first call to `cumsum()` (when decorated with `@numba.njit)` also does the compilation, so to be fair you should not time this first call. The second (and third and ...) call to `cumsum()` will be fast.